# Can I answer for my own query, if I found answer myself?

Tags: discussion

Does Stack Overflow provide or allow answering my own question if I find an answer myself?

Answer (score 4):

Sure! I too was in similar situation and question sometime back. Yes, you can answer your own question too, in fact Stack Overflow provides provision to submit your answer even at the time of registering or asking your question. I am not sure about the visibility of this option as it may be based on reputation too, but sure it is there.

It is more of a feature that helps members to share their knowledge for the benefit of others and is appreciated!

Comment: A posted answer is _always_ visible, unless it's deleted.

Comment: There also happens to be a [help page on answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Thanks Jenna Sloan, I will sure look into it.

Comment: @Cerbrus: thanks for the information on the posted answer visibility and moving my question to relevant section.

Comment: Why Stackoverflow is not showing the existence of this question when we are entering it. When I posted this question it wasn't showing the existence so naturally I thought it is new. it would be great if the validation of question existence is effectively indicated, it will save time of users and even moderators too. Thanks to everyone for their guidance and help.

Comment: @Simmam: thanks for your answer. It helped.

Comment: @Vikki There's a checkbox right under the *"Post your question"* button for immediately answering your own question. If you check it you'll get a second textfield for the answer. Not entirely sure if that's what you mean with visibility.